# How to delete row in pandas based on conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','aa','ccc','rere','thth','my desc 1','','my feature2 1'], ['1','aa','fff','flfl','ipip','my desc 2','',''], ['1','aa','mmm','rprp','','','',''], ['2','aa','ccc','rprp','','','my feature1 1',''], ['2','aa','fff','bubu','thth','my desc 3','',''], ['2','aa','mmm','fafa','rtrt','my desc 4','',''], ['3','aa','ccc','blbl','thth','my desc 5','my feature1 2','my feature2 2'], ['3','aa','fff','arar','amam','my desc 6','',''], ['3','aa','mmm','acac','ryry','my desc 7','',''],['4','bb','coco','rere','','','','my feature2 3'], ['4','bb','inin','mimi','rere','my desc 8','',''], ['4','bb','itit','toto','enen','my desc 9','',''], ['4','bb','spsp','glgl','pepe','my desc 10','',''], ['5','bb','coco','baba','mpmp','my desc 11','my feature1 3',''], ['5','bb','inin','rere','','','',''],['5','bb','itit','toto','hrhr','my desc 12','',''], ['5','bb','spsp','glgl','lolo','my desc 13','','']], columns=['foo', 'bar','name_input','value_input','bulb','desc','feature1', 'feature2'])
```

Now, I need to delete row to get the below output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','aa','ccc','rere','thth','my desc 1','','my feature2 1'], ['2','aa','ccc','rprp','','my desc 3','my feature1 1',''], ['3','aa','ccc','blbl','thth','my desc 5','my feature1 2','my feature2 2'], ['4','bb','coco','rere','','my desc 8','','my feature2 3'], ['5','bb','coco','baba','mpmp','my desc 11','my feature1 3','']], columns=['foo', 'bar','name_input','value_input','bulb','desc','feature1', 'feature2'])
```

I tried the below. And none of them seem to work.

```
df= df.dropna(subset=['feature1', 'feature2'])
df.dropna(thresh=5, axis=0, inplace=True)
df= df[df.feature2.notnull()]
df= df[pd.notnull(df[['feature1', 'feature2']])]
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `astype(bool)`

Empty strings evaluate as `False` in a boolean context.  Use `filter` to get at just the columns that start with `feature`.  Then use `astype(bool)` and followed by `any(axis=1)`

```
df[df.filter(regex='fea').astype(bool).any(1)]

   foo bar name_input value_input  bulb        desc       feature1       feature2
0    1  aa        ccc        rere  thth   my desc 1                 my feature2 1
3    2  aa        ccc        rprp                    my feature1 1               
6    3  aa        ccc        blbl  thth   my desc 5  my feature1 2  my feature2 2
9    4  bb       coco        rere                                   my feature2 3
13   5  bb       coco        baba  mpmp  my desc 11  my feature1 3
```

To match your results, we can back fill the `desc` column

```
feat = df.filter(regex='feat').astype(bool).any(1)
desc = df.desc.where(df.desc.astype(bool)).bfill()
df.assign(desc=desc)[feat]

   foo bar name_input value_input  bulb        desc       feature1       feature2
0    1  aa        ccc        rere  thth   my desc 1                 my feature2 1
3    2  aa        ccc        rprp         my desc 3  my feature1 1               
6    3  aa        ccc        blbl  thth   my desc 5  my feature1 2  my feature2 2
9    4  bb       coco        rere         my desc 8                 my feature2 3
13   5  bb       coco        baba  mpmp  my desc 11  my feature1 3
```

Comment: very slick, didn't know about strings evaluating to False, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: thank you. however "desc" column should have all values including "my desc 3" and "my desc 8" as well. How do we get that?

Comment: You need to explain why `'my desc 3'` goes where it does.

Comment: for individual foo's, desc value are mandatory. And feature 1, feature 2 are dependent on bulb. If bulb is empty then either one of feature will be empty But desc will always be present with values. And first available desc of each foo is required

Answer (score 2):

another method is to change your blank strings to true `NaN` values then pass the `how` argument to `dropna` and use `all` as the value

```
import numpy as np
df.replace('',np.nan).dropna(subset=['feature1','feature2'],how='all').fillna('')


   foo bar name_input value_input  bulb        desc       feature1  feature2
0    1  aa        ccc        rere  thth   my desc 1                 my feature2 1
3    2  aa        ccc        rprp                    my feature1 1   
6    3  aa        ccc        blbl  thth   my desc 5  my feature1 2  my feature2 2
9    4  bb       coco        rere                                   my feature2 3 
13   5  bb       coco        baba  mpmp  my desc 11  my feature1 3
```